# Memory leak in Python http server

Tags: python, http, memory-management, server, memory-leaks

I am running a server that accepts base64 encoded images, it takes those images and runs them through a tflite model. When I start sending images to a server (there are a lot because they are captured from a webcam feed), memory usage goes through the roof (over 10gb), before crashing my computer.

Here is the server:

```
class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_POST(self):
    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
    post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode('utf-8')
    parsed_data = json.loads(post_data)
    snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
    try:
        letter, conf = getHands(parsed_data['base64Img'].split(',')[-1])
        letter = letter.split('\n')[0].split(' ')[-1]
    except:
        letter = ''
        conf = ''
        print("No Hands Detected")
    res = json.loads(f'{{"letter": "{letter}", "conf": "{conf}"}}')
    with open('debug.txt', '+a') as FO:
        for i in stats:
            FO.write(str(i))
            FO.write('\n\n')
    self._set_response(200)
    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(res).encode('utf-8'))

def _set_response(self, status_code):
    self.send_response(status_code)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, port=5001):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print(f"Starting server on port {port}...")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

As you can see I am already trying to find the leak with tracemalloc, but I can't seem to find anything that would look very suspicious.

If anything else is needed, or the leak couldn't be in this part of the code I can of course provide other parts as well.